# Incorrect owner and last edit date when viewing unanswered questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502335/transitivity-of-auto-specialization-in-ghc), which still doesn't have an answer. It hasn't been edited many times, so it is *not* a community wiki. However, when I [view unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered), it is the #1 unanswered question. But it shows that it is owned by "community" and was edited two days ago, neither of which is the case. What's up with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not showing that it's *owned* by Community. It's showing that it was *modified last* by Community, 2 days ago. That is because 2 days ago users posted two abusive answers to your question which have since been deleted, along with the users who posted them. Since the posts and accounts no longer exist, Community takes the blame for the modification.

Comment: Interesting. Can I view said abusive answers, or at least see a record of their existence? Also, some mods did some quick work with that since I never got any sort of notification of an answer!

Comment: @Eric Well, one is just a bunch of random letters, and the other is an offensive message I don't think you want to see.

Comment: I'll take your word for that :-)